# No log messages after Spring Boot upgrade

Tags: spring-boot

I have recently upgraded spring boot from 1.1.10 to 1.2.0. I did not specify version information for spring boot dependencies like spring mvc. So they also got upgraded.

After upgrade, I am not able to see any log information from spring.
I am able to see the sysout and syserr information of my code though.

Did any thing change in the latest relese ?

Comment: Did you customize logging configuration? Do you use Logback (default) or another logging framework?

Comment: Please see my possible answer below or are you missing log messages from the framework and you so see output form your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry folks, I have a log4j.properties in my class path. That configuration file prevented entries from springframework packages. Not sure how it ended up there though. Probably 1.1.10 is not picking it up. Things might have changed with 1.2.0. Hence the problem. Once I deleted that file, every thing is working fine

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

As per the changelog [Spring Boot 1.2.0 changelog](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.2-Release-Notes#logging-output) Spring Boot's default behavior is to not write any log files.